# How to Export CloudWatch Logs (result of a Lambda function) to S3 using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following requirement. I need to export Logs from Cloudwatch to S3 using Terraform. I have couple of Lambda functions and Logs from  these Lambda function are automatically getting logged to Cloudwatch /aws/lambda/. I am  looking at a provision to export these logs to S3 for developer viewing.

I have looked at following implementation for pushing the Cloudwatch logs using CloudTrail to S3. This example uses few applications which doesn't cover Lambda feature.

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/trussworks/logs/aws/1.4.0

Can I follow any similar apporach in creating a Policy that can let the Logs logged from Lambda function to Cloudwatch can be pushed to S3?

Is creating the Policy is the only requirement for pushing the Cloudwatch logs to S3?  Is there any way I can tell the Cloudwatch to push all the logs it has instead of pinning on specific feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subscriptions to get access to a real-time feed of log events from CloudWatch Logs and have it delivered to other services such as an Amazon Kinesis stream, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose stream, or AWS Lambda for custom processing, analysis, or loading to other systems or S3
```/* kinesis stream */

```
resource "aws_kinesis_stream" "log_stream" {
  name             = "test-logs"
  shard_count      = 1
  retention_period = 24

  shard_level_metrics = [
    "IncomingBytes",
    "OutgoingBytes",
    "IncomingRecords",
    "IteratorAgeMilliseconds",
    "OutgoingRecords",
    "ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
    "WriteProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
  ]

  tags {
    EnvironmentType = "test"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cloudwatchlogs_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["logs.${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

```
some thing of this sort

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS firehose to send logs from CWL to S3: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.html

Comment: The link is now broken